# How to add gesture detect swipe operation on list view builder in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

Need to implement bottom to top swipe on flutter screen which contains the List view builder widget that loads the list of element.

Answer (score 1):

```
   ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();

    void scrollToTop() {
      SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        if (_controller.hasClients) {
          _controller.animateTo(
            _controller.position.maxScrollExtent,
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
            curve: Curves.elasticInOut,
          );
        }
      });
    }
```

and use `scrollToTop();`